# How to make edittext to editable and non edittable by spinner selection

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need edittext to be changed according to the spinner value
its working for `keylistener(null)` for non editable but i am not able to get it back and since focus shouldn't loose from edittext I am not using this `setEnabled` method
I am using this code

```
    sp_card.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                final int pos, long arg3) {
            if (filteredCardsList.get(pos).awardPointsRatio != null
                    && filteredCardsList.get(pos).awardPointsRatio == 0.0) {
                et_award_points.setText("");
                et_award_points.setHint("No ratio is available");
                et_award_points.setKeyListener(et_award_points
                        .getKeyListener());
            } else {
                et_award_points.setKeyListener(null);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Here `et_award_points` becomes always non-editable field its not changing to its state back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.It works

```
private KeyListener listener;
listener = et_award_points.getKeyListener();
et_award_points.setKeyListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `editTextInstance.setEnabled(true)` to made it editable,  `editTextInstance.setEnabled(false)` to disable

Comment: I need edittext always enabled because values should change accordingly when i came from one to other edittext

Answer (score 0):

Change your button to ToggleButton and implement this code , this should be the best solution I reckon

```
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            editText.setEnabled(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

Comment: its not a button it is a spinner. According to the value I choose the edittext should be editable or non editable but it should not remove focus